# Representations of minimal model primary fields in the Coulomb-gas Formalism

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, conformal-field-theory

This question is a cross-post from MO [(link)](https://mathoverflow.net/q/422202/430549).

Is it known how to construct the primary field *operators* of the unitary minimal models $\mathcal{M}(m+1,m)$ in the Coulomb gas formalism? As far as I can tell, the original work of Dotsenko and Fateev [2] is limited to the 4-point functions and does not give a direct definition of the field operators (as honest operators, on some not-necessarily "minimal" Hilbert space(s)) themselves (though, at a physicist's level of rigor, it should fix the N-point functions via the conformal bootstrap, which ought then determine the field operators via a reconstruction theorem). The (physics?) paper [3] of Felder seems to me to strongly suggest that such a direct definition is possible. But, as far as I can tell, it itself falls a bit short of a rigorous definition.

A related question question is: for which primary fields in which minimal models are all $N$-point functions known in some closed form? All $N$-point functions are known for all fields in the critical Ising model, but is that it (besides the free field)? Are there any other nontrivial fields in any other minimal models for which the $N$-point functions are known in this way? (Of course, the $N$-point functions should be determined via the $3$-point functions via the conformal bootstrap, but this shouldn't count as being in closed form.)

Here is my incomplete attempt at making sense of Felder's definition in the simplest interesting case, the spin field in the critical Ising model $\mathcal{M}(4,3)$. Hopefully this will indicate what I have in mind, but unfortunately it requires a bit of explanation. First, some generalities about vertex operators. I will use the notation of [3][4]. In [3], we have defined some Verma models $\mathcal{F}_{\alpha,\alpha_0}$ of a central extension of the Heisenberg algebra that also come equipped with representations of the Virasoro algebra. Here, $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ is arbitrary and $\alpha_0$ is some fixed number. For each $z\in \mathbb{C}$ and $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$, we have a formal vertex operator $V_{\beta}(z)$ which is defined as a binary form $$\mathcal{F}_{\alpha+\beta,\alpha_0}\times\mathcal{F}_{\alpha,\alpha_0} \to \mathbb{C}$$ (see pg. 14 of [5]). In [5] is constructed a nested 1-parameter family $\{\mathcal{H}_{\alpha,\alpha_0,r}\}_{r>0}$ of completions of $\mathcal{F}_{\alpha,\alpha_0}$, and then it can be shown that, whenever $r<|z|<R$, $V_\beta(z)$ defines a Hilbert-Schmidt (in particular, bounded) map $\mathcal{H}_{\alpha,\alpha_0,r}\to \mathcal{H}_{\alpha+\beta,\alpha_0,R}$ depending analytically on $z$. Then, for $z_1,\ldots,z_N$ with $r<|z_N|<\cdots<|z_1|<R$ we have a composition $V_{\beta_1}(z_1)\cdots V_{\beta_N}(z_N)$ which is well-defined in the sense that it does not depend on which intermediate $\mathcal{H}_{\bullet,\alpha_0,\rho}$'s we use. One can then show that the product analytically continues to the universal cover of the moduli space $\mathcal{M}_{N,r,R}$ of $N$ distinct points in the annulus $\{z: r<|z|<R\}$. In fact, the universal cover is overkill, and it continues to the cover corresponding to the commutator subgroup of $\pi_1(\mathcal{M}_{N,r,R})$.  Now here is the bit specific to the Ising model: let
$$ \mathcal{H}_r = \overline{\bigoplus}_{s\in \mathbb{Z}} \mathcal{H}_{s\sqrt{3}/4,\alpha_0,r}\otimes \mathcal{H}_{s\sqrt{3}/4,\alpha_0,r},$$
where $\alpha_0 = 1/(4\sqrt{3})$, and, for $C_1,C_2>0$,
$$ \sigma(z) = C_1 V_{\sqrt{3}/4}(z)V_{\sqrt{3}/4}(z^*) +C_2 \Big( \int_{P(z)}V_{-\sqrt{3}/2}(w)V_{\sqrt{3}/4}(z) \,\mathrm{d} w \Big)\Big( \int_{P(z^*)}V_{-\sqrt{3}/2}(w^*)V_{\sqrt{3}/4}(z^*) \,\mathrm{d} w^* \Big),$$
which we consider as a *bounded* operator $\mathcal{H}_r\to \mathcal{H}_R$ for $r<|z|<R$. Here $P(z) \in [\pi_1(\mathcal{M}_{N,r,R}),\pi_1(\mathcal{M}_{N,r,R})]$ is a Pochhammer contour with respect to $z$ and the origin. (The $V(z)$'s are acting on the left factors of the tensor products, and the $V(z^*)$'s are acting on the right factors.) This should be a well-defined $(1,2)$-primary field, and I suspect that it is (in some appropriate sense) the critical Ising spin field. So, I believe that for an appropriate choice of $C_1C_2$ (only the product shows up in correlation functions with $|0,\alpha_0\rangle \in \mathcal{F}_{0,\alpha_0}$), we have
$$ \langle \alpha_0,0| \sigma(z_1)\cdots \sigma(z_N)|0,\alpha_0\rangle = \Big[ \sum_{\substack{\varsigma_1,\ldots,\varsigma_N \in \{-1,+1\} \\ \varsigma_1+\cdots+\varsigma_N = 0}} \prod_{1\leq m < n \leq N} |z_m-z_n|^{\varsigma_m\varsigma_n/2} \Big]^{1/2}. $$
This is automatically true for $N$ odd, and for $N=2$ we have, via a surprisingly nontrivial computation, $$\langle \alpha_0,0| \sigma(z_1)\sigma(z_2)|0,\alpha_0\rangle \propto C_1C_2 |z_1-z_2|^{-1/4},$$ where the constant of proportionality is explicitly computable (and nonzero), so the question is whether or not this continues to hold for $N=4,6,8,\cdots$. For any $N\in 2\mathbb{N}^+$, the left-hand side is some explicit iterated contour integral, but I do not know how to compute it. I tested the conjecture for the 4-point function numerically, and there is complete agreement in this case.

References:

[[1](https://mathoverflow.net/q/422202/430549)] https://mathoverflow.net/q/422202/430549

[2] Dotsenko and Fateev, *Conformal algebra and multipoint correlation functions in 2D statistical models*

[3] Felder, BRST Approach to Minimal Models

[4] Francesco, Mathieu, and Senechal, *Conformal Field Theory*, Section 9.B

[5] Bovier, *A rigorous treatment of conformal blocks in a model of bosonic conformal field theory*